# Is there a way that the for loop can always check a value of variable outside this loop in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop, sprite-kit

I am trying to create nodes through for loop in sprite kit but I want every time the "for loop" wants to create a new node to check if a value outside the loop if it is changed( depending on this value the node created). 
what I want to do is in CreatSquares function

Sorry for my bad English

```
import SpriteKit

import GameplayKit

var Score = 0

class GameScene: SKScene {

let SquareSide = 100
var touchedNode = SKNode()
var touchLocation = CGPoint()
let ScoreLabel = SKLabelNode()

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    CreatSquares()

    }


func CreatSquares(){
    for _ in 0...100{

        /*===========================================================================================
        ((((((((  I want here while creating nodes if the score is equal (let's say) to 20 ->>>> change in SquareSide or change anything in square's properties ))))))))

         The problem is that the 100 square created together
         ================================================================================================
        */

      let square = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(x: Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.frame.width))), y: Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.frame.height))), width: SquareSide, height: SquareSide))
        if Score <= 10{
            square.fillColor = UIColor.orange}
        else{
        square.fillColor = UIColor.blue
        }
    square.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: square.frame.width, height: square.frame.height), center: CGPoint(x: square.position.x, y: square.position.y))
    square.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    square.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    square.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 0
    square.name = "square"
        self.addChild(square)



    }


}
func CreatScoreLabel(){
let ScoreLabel = SKLabelNode()
    ScoreLabel.text = "Your Score is:\(Score)"
    ScoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width/2, y: self.frame.height - 50)
    ScoreLabel.color = UIColor.white
    self.addChild(ScoreLabel)

}

func updatScore(){
 ScoreLabel.text = "Your Score is:\(Score)"

}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)
        touchedNode = self.atPoint(touchLocation)
        if touchedNode.name == "square"{
            Score += 1
            touchedNode.removeFromParent()
            }


    }

    }

override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    updatScore()
}
```

}

Comment: why not if any value which is globally declared and modified by background thread then you can access such value within foor loop

Comment: @ShobhakarTiwari What does it matter if it is a background thread in this case? In SpriteKit, manipulating with nodes must be performed on a main thread (as per docs), so it is likely that OP does his for loop on a main thread(just before using those nodes).